# What happens when shutdown/reboot is executed?

Tags: scripts

Which scripts are executed when we click on shutdown or reboot?

Using Ubuntu 14.04.5.

Comment: Your graphical display manager instructs all programs to terminate and then runs halt. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76706/what-happens-when-i-press-shut-down-from-the-gui and you would need to dig through the GDM / KDM documentation for details.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you asking about?

Comment: I have edited the question to include Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until 15.04 `upstart` was used for this, then being replaced by `systemd`.

---

#### Used until Ubuntu 15.04: upstart

When you press the shutdown button or execute `shutdown +0` in a terminal, `upstart` executes every script in **`/etc/rc0.d`** in alphabetical order.

When you press the reboot button or execute `shutdown -r +0` in a terminal, `upstart` executes every script in **`/etc/rc6.d`** in alphabetical order.

**Edit:** Note that the `+0` in the above commands indicates the number of minutes to wait prior to taking the requested action and is equivalent to `now`. If you have other users on the system it would be prudent to increase this value to allow them time to save their work.

Both directories hold only symlinks whose targets are located in
**`/etc/init.d/`** though.

For more information see `/etc/init.d/README` and `man init`.

#### Used from Ubuntu 15.04 on: systemd

Here some links concerning `systemd`:

- “SystemdForUpstartUsers” on [wiki.ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers)
- exhaustive article “[Understanding Systemd Units and Unit Files](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files)”

Comment: depends on version of Ubuntu ;) Ubuntu uses systemd so https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-halt.service.html

Comment: 14.04 (which is still supported as of this date) uses upstart, not systemd. Expanding your answer to include that version or at least making it clear which version your answer applies to would improve it. :-)

Comment: @dessert I edited it as well, your welcome.